# Trouble styling a disabled image button jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm again at a loss here. I have tried a ton of different things to get this image button to look disabled WITHOUT losing my image. I am providing the Javascript here of how the button is disabled:

```js
$('#button2').attr('data-href', $('#button2').attr('href'));
$('#button2').attr('data-onclick', $('#button2').attr('onclick'));
$('#button2').attr('href', '#');
$('#button2').attr('onclick', 'return');
$('#button2').button('disabled');
```

This is my HTML of the button that is being disabled based on what the user is allowed to look use in this application:

```html
<div data-role="content" >
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <a  href="page1.html" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" id="button1"><img src="image.png" alt="Browse" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <a href="page2.html" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" id="button2"><img src="image.png" alt="Search" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally this is the CSS I have been working with that I have seen documented to work with CSS3:

```css
button[disabled],
button[disabled]:active {
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Well the HTML has no buttons so there's nothing to disable. What you have are anchors. You'll need to use CSS to adjust the appearance of the anchor to make it look disabled. But, because it's an anchor, it'll never really be disabled unless you kill the click with jquery.

Comment: That is what is boggling me. The JS is disabling the button from going to page2.html but it looks like a broken button. Is there a better way to go about this button and keep the image inside?

Comment: First, stop calling it a "button". Nowhere is there a button. It's an anchor tag with an image. You could do something like $('#button2').click(function() { $(this).css({'opacity': '0.3'}); return false; }); Actual button elements are written as <button> and that's what "button" refers to when dealing with html or javascript.

Comment: Ok, well that is what I know too but using data-role="button" for jQuery Mobile makes this appear and act as a button. I will give your JQ a try though. Thank you Scott.

Comment: The above didn't work for this, thank you though. I'll keep looking and trying.

Comment: hmm.. seems to work (http://jsfiddle.net/5py5a/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `href` to disable and put it back to enable. Visually you can use `opacity: .5;` to make it appear disabled.

```
$( '#button2' ).removeAttr( 'href' );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Y7v7w/

HTML:

```html
<div data-role="content" >
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <a  href="page1.html" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" id="button1"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/48x48/actions/agt_login.png" alt="Browse" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <a href="page2.html" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" id="button2"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/48x48/actions/agt_login.png" alt="Search" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```js
$( '#button2' ).css( 'opacity', '.5' );
$( '#button2' ).removeAttr( 'href' );
```